# Do the attributes of sqoop command follow some syntactical order?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

For example

$ sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb \
--username root \
--table emp_add \
--m 1 \          (or --num-mappers 10)
--where “city =’abcd’” \
--target-dir /whereque

is same as?

$ sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb \
--username root \
--table emp_add \
--where “city =’abcd’” \
--target-dir /whereque
--m 1 \          (or --num-mappers 10)

I tried above two options and it worked. But my question is can we jumble up the attributes for all the cases?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop command usually follows this syntax:

`sqoop command [GENERIC-ARGS] [TOOL-ARGS]`

> You cannot change the order of the usage. However you can change order of the tool-args.

For more have a look at [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have any generic argument in your code. Generic arguments are related to "configuration" settings. There are listed below:

```
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
-jt <local|jobtracker:port>    specify a job tracker
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop command is shown below:

```
sqoop import [GENERIC-ARGS] [TOOL-ARGS]
```

**Please see some points below on the order in which Command should be executed.**

1.Generic arguments must always be placed after tool name

2.All generic arguments must always be placed before tool arguments

3.Generic arguments are always preceded by single dash(-) character.

4.Tool arguments are always preceded with 2 dashes(--), exception to which     is single character arguments